# Dynamic height for material ui tab containers

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I'm having a problem which at first I thought it was the general configuration of my app and the height I was giving to my page wrapping classes. But I made a simple out of the box material ui tab example and it seems this is natural to material ui Tabs Component.

Material UI tabs component gives their tab container the same height, being that height the largest of all its containers. So if you have one tab content with lots of content in it, it makes the other tab contents just as large, even though they may only have one text field and a button in them.

How can I make it that the height of the container adjusts to the content of its own tab?

Here is a visual
[image]

Here is why TAB ONE is so large, TAB TWO is setting the height
[image]

[**Here is a webpackBin**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KxzPDCX094UXe9TyBSN) for you to see the code working and mess with it.

One hack I've done so far is setting a definite height and overflow, but I don't want to do that because it creates a double scroll bar (one in the tab container, one in the body) besides, it's buggy looking.

I would like it if the tab container (the one with the green border) adjusts to the content as it does in TAB TWO, ***BUT*** individually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does WebpackBin always take forever to load? Anyway, take a look at this version, my amendments should be evident - but if you have any questions feel free to ask: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ky0z8h7PsdTYOddK3LG

Comment: lol. Yeah react libraries are rather large. I'll check it out

Comment: WOW! That easy! I'm ashamed :( hahaha. Post the answer. You deserve credit, plus I saw several material ui PRs in their github for this and no solution. I'm sure this will help others

Comment: Sure - would be happy to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a merge request that have been accepted here on the lib that could be interesting with a new method called `updateHeight` https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views/pull/359

```
<SwipeableViews
  action={actions => {
    this.swipeableActions = actions;
  }}
  animateHeight
>
    <div>{'slide n°1'}</div>
    <div>{'slide n°2'}</div>
    <div>{'slide n°3'}</div>
</SwipeableViews>
```

Then:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.swipeableActions.updateHeight();
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this rigth away. This issue just happened to have circled back to my desk yesterday So you came just in time. Thanks. I'll update

Comment: That is a mch better solution and the accepted answer

Comment: Hey bud. Have you tested this when items within the tab are hidden and update the height when shown? It seems the updateHeight locks the loaded height and hidden items do not show until I change tabs. Then the updateHeight fires and updates the height for the newly shown items to be seen. Confusing, I know. We could do a chat if you need screenshots. I could use your help since you're the only who answered with this

Comment: If I understand well what you mean, your content depends on user actions? So I think you need to call `this.swipeableActions.updateHeight();` when you show your content in the tab and not only in `componentDidUpdate` method of the global component.
If I don't understand well, could you post a codepen example or something like that?

Comment: You understood. I figured that out shortly after I messaged you and it works but it messes other things up that also change the height. I've decided to remove swipeable views from the app. Not worth the trouble. Its only value is the sliding animation

Comment: It's too bad you can't keep it. Maybe if you still wanna persevere a little bit, you can create an issue on the github project ^^

Answer (score 12):

If you set the height based on the given element's current visibility you will be able to resolve this issue.

#### Example

```
.react-swipeable-view-container > div[aria-hidden="false"] {
    height: 100%;
}

.react-swipeable-view-container > div[aria-hidden="true"] {
    height: 0;
}
```

Note: this solution could be improved by using a better selector, something more descriptive like a class name. I suppose it's subjective though, using an attribute selector is not technically wrong and actually more specific than just a class.

**Demonstration:** https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ky0z8h7PsdTYOddK3LG

Comment: I think the selector targetted is perfectly fine since it's generated by ReactDOM and this will probably never change. MaterialUI4 may be different.

Comment: Ok, perfect then it should be scalable

Comment: exactly what i was looking for

Comment: This non-javascript solution ist the best. Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

`animateHeight` will animate height on tab change. if all tabs have different height it will show height accordingly. 

**Example:**

```
<SwipeableViews
  animateHeight // it will animate height on tab change
>
    <div>{'slide 1'}</div>
    <div>{'slide 2'}</div>
    <div>{'slide 3'}</div>
</SwipeableViews>
```

Happy Coding ...!